# display achor tag in angular Js expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I am not able to display the anchor tag inside the AngularJS expression. The problem is that when I am trying to display an anchor tag as an icon which is being fetched from the API, it's only displaying the raw path as

```
a href='../UserControls/DownloadRLCSFile.ashx?Path=\\dotnetdev\csv\RLCSDocuments\Registrations\ABACF\E.S.I.C. Registration\Sample.xlsx' target='_blank' download><i class='fa fa-download' style='font-size: 13pt;' ></i></a>
```

Please find the below code:

```
<div id="Div2" ng-controller="BasicRegulatoryDetail"> 
  <h4 class="padder-sm  b-b"><b>Regulatory Updates</b></h4>

  <div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped bg-white ">
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="bs in BasicInfo" >
            <td><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="~/RLCS_Connect/RegulatoryUpdateDetails.aspx?Subject={{bs.Subject}}" runat="server">{{bs.Subject}}</asp:HyperLink></td>  
            <td>{{bs.Document_Path}}</td> //here i am facing the problem
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might need ng-href:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

The wrong way to write it:

```
<a href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}">link1</a>
```

The correct way to write it:

```
<a ng-href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}">link1</a>
```