# display anchor tag in angular expressions enclosed by html tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I want to display an anchor tag inside angular expression enclosed by html tag. when I am using it inside html tag, it is displaying the raw path as it is which is:

```
<a href='../UserControls/DownloadRLCSFile.ashx?Path=\\\\dotnetdev\\csv\\RLCSDocuments\\Registrations\\ABACF\\E.S.I.C. Registration\\Sample.xlsx' target='_blank' download><i class='fa fa-download' style='font-size: 13pt;' ></i></a> Code :
<div id="Div2" ng-controller="BasicRegulatoryDetail">
    <!--added by dilip -->
    <h4 class="padder-sm  b-b"><b>Regulatory Updates</b></h4>
    <div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped bg-white ">
                <%--<thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Subject</th>
                        <th>Download</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>--%>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="bs in BasicInfo">
                            <td>
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="~/RLCS_Connect/RegulatoryUpdateDetails.aspx?Subject={{bs.Subject}}" runat="server">{{bs.Subject}}</asp:HyperLink>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{bs.Document_Path}}</td>//here i am facing the problem </tr>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display achor tag in angular Js expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773870/display-achor-tag-in-angular-js-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-bind-html` something like

```
<td><span ng-bind-html='bs.Document_Path'></span></td>
```